# Can we 'square root' a principal ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I was doing an exercise in Algebraic Number Theory and I encountered a problem.

Suppose I have a number field, say $K$, and its ring of integers, say ${O}_K$ such that $\sqrt{d}\in O_K$ for some non-square $d$.

Suppose now I have an ideal in $O_K$, say $I$. I do not know if it is principal or not but the only information I have is that $I^2=(d)$ (so $I^2$ **is** principal). Can I therefore deduce that $I=(\sqrt{d})$?

It is very tempting to just say $(\sqrt{d})(\sqrt{d})=(d)=I^2$ and thus $I=(\sqrt{d})$ but I am not sure if that is allowed?

I guess I could have also started using that $O_K$ is a Dedekind domain or maybe that any ideal $I$ is generated by at most two elements but I am not sure if that is making it worse?

I hope I explained my question sufficiently clearly, many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not true in general that $I^2$ principal implies $I$ is principal, but fractional ideals in a Dedekind domain have unique factorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is true. Use that ideals factor uniquely into prime ideals in Dedekind domains. We get $I^2 = \mathfrak{p}_1^{2e_1} \dots \mathfrak{p}_k^{2e_k}$ for $e_1, \dots, e_k \in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, say $(\sqrt{d}) = \mathfrak{q}_1^{d_1} \dots q_{\ell}^{d_{\ell}}$. So we get $$ \mathfrak{q}_1^{2d_1} \dots \mathfrak{q}_{\ell}^{2d_{\ell}} = (\sqrt{d})^2 = (d) = I^2 = \mathfrak{p}_1^{2e_1} \dots \mathfrak{p}_k^{2e_k}.$$ Comparing primes yields $I = (\sqrt{d})$.